# web.config transformations not showing up in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

I just added three configurations to my web application. I then right clicked web.config and selected "Add Config Transforms". The three files were created, but there is no expander next to web.config in the solution explorer and the transforms are not applied when deployed (Build Deployment Package).

I've rebuilt the solution, dragged the files into the solution explorer, Add>Existing Item, and closed/reopened VS. Still not showing up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VB strikes again. VB applications don't show them unless "Show all files" is selected. Brilliant.

Comment: It looks like this is still a problem in VS 2012.

Comment: Also in VS 2017

Comment: "VB strikes again" - made my day :)